# Importing Finder Folders to Albums in Photos app

Tags: finder, photos, photos.app, folders

I organize all of my photos into folders. I have years of photos organized properly by year_date_event_name. I would like to import the folders directly into the Photos app as Albums named as the folder name.

I can't seem to even find a way to import the folders as albums, let alone having the folder name used as the album name.

I'm guessing a script would be the best way to do this? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dragging a folder into iPhoto would create an album with the name of the folder. I don't know if that works anymore. Beware though, dragging more than one won't create folders for each.

Comment: I tried it and it does not work anymore.

Comment: Another simple, useful, almost-every-other-app-even-iPhoto-has-it feature they removed/neglected because of god-knows-why :(